# Truffle test failing

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-contract, ethereumj, truffle-test

i am learning solidity contracts and ethereum dapps. I have created a smart contract for creating a ERC20 token on using truffle dev environment.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract LearnTokens {
    string  public name = "LearnToken";
    string  public symbol = "LT";
    string  public standard = "LearnToken Token v1.0";
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    event Transfer(
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _to,
        uint256 _value
    );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    function LearnToken (uint256 _initialSupply) public payable{
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);


        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;



        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

        return true;
    } }
```

This is my migration file

```
var LearnToken = artifacts.require("./LearnToken.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(LearnToken,100);
};
```

And When i try to run truffle test, it throws following error.

```
1) Contract: LearnToken
       sets the total supply upon deployment:

      sets the total supply to 100
      + expected - actual

      -0
      +100
```

I have  assumed it here that when i run **truffle migrate**, it sets the initial supply to 100, as i have seen in a tutorial. Am i getting this right or there is another way? TIA

Comment: Have a look to this: https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript

Comment: @Aniket Thanks. Can i also write tests for **function transferFrom**. Can you guide ?

Comment: See https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/test/token/ERC20/ERC20.test.js#L76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon running `truffle migrate` your contract will not set anything to initial supply. It has no constructor. Upon close inspection I found that you have a `function`

```
function LearnToken (uint256 _initialSupply) public payable{
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
    totalSupply = _initialSupply;
}
```

Are you trying to make it your `constructor`? The function name doesn't match with your contract name. Even if it matched you will get another error as you are using solidity version `^5.0.0`. You need to write your `constructor` as below

```
constructor (uint256 _initialSupply) public payable{
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
    totalSupply = _initialSupply;
}
```